# createEvent('Event');

Tags: javascript

I have a working script from someone, there in is this line:

```
    this.event = document.createEvent('Event');
```

When i look up documentation i always see a few possibilities listed to use, like mouseEvent, 'Event' is never listed.

Is 'Event' a real event? Or is it not?

And he has:

```
    this.event = document.createEvent('Event');
    this.event.initEvent('shake', true, true);
```

I want to be able to trigger 4 different event's back.
Is this the proper way?

```
    this.event1 = document.createEvent('Event');
    this.event1.initEvent('betaAwayTick', true, true);
    this.event2 = document.createEvent('Event');
    this.event2.initEvent('betaAwayHold', true, true);
    this.event3 = document.createEvent('Event');
    this.event3.initEvent('betaTowardsTick', true, true);
    this.event4 = document.createEvent('Event');
    this.event4.initEvent('betaTowardsHold', true, true);
```

Or is this overkill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the other event types implement/inherit the `Event` interface. See the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event).

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent) also lists it in the list of DOM 3 events:

> Basic events module | "Event" (Gecko also supports "Events") | [event.initEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initEvent)